# Simulated Annealing in Python, Variables in While loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, simulated-annealing

Having successfully written a Genetic Algorithm, I'm now writing a simulated annealing program for comparing against the GA , but can't seem to get it to reach any kind of optimum never mind the global one.

After a bit of testing I think the problem seems to be passing variables back into the while loop.  For testing purposes I have changed the code to basically only accept solutions which have a lower energy delta than the previous solution so I should expect the variable which stores the best solution to only show a lower number but in fact is fluctuating and always returning the most recent solution whether or not it is better.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
while temperature >0.01:
    solutionlength = len(Solution)
    NeighbourSolution = Solution
    switch1 = i % solutionlength
    i +=random.randint(0,100)
    switch2 = i % solutionlength
    NeighbourSolution[switch1], NeighbourSolution[switch2] = NeighbourSolution[switch2], NeighbourSolution[switch1]
    EnergyOld = Solution.get_changeover_times()
    EnergyNew = NeighbourSolution.get_changeover_times()
    EnergyDelta = EnergyNew - EnergyOld

    if EnergyDelta < 0:
        acceptanceprob = 1

    else:
        acceptanceprob = 0 #math.exp(-EnergyDelta/temperature)

    if acceptanceprob > 0: #random.random():
        Solution = NeighbourSolution

    if Solution.get_changeover_times() < bestsolution.get_changeover_times():
        bestsolution = Solution

    print (bestsolution.get_changeover_times())

    temperature -= coolingrate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not "passing variables back into the while loop" because you can only pass variables into a function, not a loop.

The problem is that a line like `NeighbourSolution = Solution` or `bestsolution = Solution` merely makes both names point to the same object. Therefore, if you change e.g. `Solution` you are also changing `bestsolution`. And of course, when you compare `bestsolution.get_changeover_times()` to `Solution.get_changeover_times()`, the changeover times of an object will never be less than the changeover times of *the same object.*

The solution is to make a *copy* of the object rather than just assigning an additional name to it. I don't know what kind of object your `Solution` is, but if it's a list subclass, you could use `Solution[:]` to copy it. Or it may have a `.copy()` method, or you can use the `copy` module. For example:

```
from copy import copy

# ...

bestsolution = copy(Solution)
```

`copy.copy()` is a *shallow copy,* meaning that it creates a new top-level object but places in it references to the same objects contained by the original object. If that doesn't work entirely, try `copy.deepcopy()`, which also makes copies of the contained objects, and any objects they contain, and so on.

Comment: Since we don't know what kind of object `Solution` is, wouldn't `copy.deepcopy()` be a better choice?

Comment: Well, possibly. Usually shallow copies work fine, and since they're faster and use less memory, I start there. Added some stuff about `deepcopy` to the answer though.

Comment: That makes sense. The Solution object is a class object which pulls together what is effectively a list of lists. If I were to define this as a function then would then instantiate the solution to overcome this?